# How do you add existing header-only source files to android studio?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-studio

This has to be the dumbest question I've had to ask in a while:

How do I add existing C/C++ source headers to the project listing in android studio?

I have a project for android I'm working on, and I'd like to add some header-only libraries to the project. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get them into android studio for easier browsing.

I can add C/C++ files by adding them to the corresponding CMake file, but I have no idea how Android Studio decides which header files should be in the application source tree, and it's not finding all the headers I'm actually using.

Frankly, I'm not sure how android studio found the C header files it *does* show, since they're not listed in *any* of the project files you're supposed to edit.

Doing a bulk text-search of the entire project directory for one of the headers that are found finds *a single* mention of the file in the `.idea/workspace.xml` file, but I experimented adding the additional file headers there, and as soon as I open android studio, it removes the added filename, and it doesn't get shown in the UI anyways.

How the heck are you supposed to do this?

Comment: Assuming you're using cmake, you could do `target_include_directories(mytarget "path/to/include/directory")`

Comment: @Justin - It's using cmake *somewhere*. Android studio has the most convoluted and opaque build process I've ever encountered, and I'm frankly not sure how it decides what files to list in the UI at all.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.0 and lower do not do a good job showing header files in C++. I'm working on improving this for a future release.

Here's how it works today. If Android Studio is given a .cpp or .c file then it will display a .h file that has the exact same base name (if it exists). So if project contains basename.cpp the basename.h will be in the Android view as well.

One way to see all the files in your project is to switch from Android view to Project Files view. This may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think what he is looking for is to add the existing .h files. If I am using libc++ then including <map> or <string> etc.